# how should I get access to DOM elements and also wants loop and add X or O on the board

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I just want to Add X or O on the board whenever a user clicks at any cell on the board.

Class cell's X and item's X are for just experiment.

By `placeMark` function X or O will be marked in the board

```js
let x = 'X'
let o = 'O'
let xTurn = true
const board = document.getElementById("board")
const cell = document.getElementsByClassName("cell")

cell.forEach(cell => {
  cell.classList.remove(x)
  cell.classList.remove(o)
  cell.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
  cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {
    once: true
  })
})

function handleClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target
  const currentClass = xTurn ? x : o
  placeMark(cell, currentClass)
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass)
}
```

```html
<div class="board" id="board">
  <div class="cell x" id="item 1"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 2"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 3"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 4"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 5"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 6"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 7"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 8"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item 9"></div>
</div>
```

edited!!

I am using VS Code.

Comment: There can be repeated class but not repeated id in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GMCgit mentioned, your IDs are not unique. You are not allowed to use space in the `id` attribute, so this has to be changed to `id="item-1"` or something similar.

Also, `cell` in your case is an HTMLCollection. `.forEach` is a method used for arrays. If you want to store your cells in array, better use `.querySelectorAll('.cell')`.

Also, you are not switching `xTurn` anywhere. Please note that your `X` and `O` are capitalized, so you have to use uppercase "X" and "O" in your CSS.

I have added a working example with a little bit of CSS just to show the effect.

```js
let x = 'X'
let o = 'O'
let xTurn = true
const board = document.getElementById("board")
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")

cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.classList.remove(x, o)
  cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {
    once: true
  })
})

function handleClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target;
  const currentClass = xTurn ? x : o;

  placeMark(cell, currentClass);

  xTurn = !xTurn;
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass)
}
```

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 306px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cell:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cell.X:after {
  content: 'X';
}

.cell.O:after {
  content: 'O';
}
```

```html
<div class="board" id="board">
  <div class="cell" id="item-1"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-2"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-3"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-4"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-5"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-6"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-7"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-8"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="item-9"></div>
</div>
```

I have deleted unnecessary code so the demo to work.

Comment: Thankyou it worked but I Didn't use querySelectorAll, I use Array.Prototype.forEach.call is this a good way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your ids repeat which is not really good and you can use:

```
const cell = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
```

Comment: I changed my Ids to Item 1, Item 2 ..... Item 9, and also update                                        
const cell = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");                           but I am trying to loop and update using classlist it's not happing as you can also see in the code that I've mentioned

Comment: In your handleClick function you are defining const cell = e.target but you also defined cell as an array, so try changing that line to targetedCell for example, basically what applies for ids (that they need to be unique) you want to do that for variable names

Comment: I am getting an error that  Uncaught TypeError: cell.forEach is not a function.

Comment: This is because you try to iterate through HTMLCollection, and not through an array.